# Problema al intentar usar INSERT y UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hola estaba practicando un poco, me encontré con dos errores, agregar nuevos usuarios y editarlos, ya revise linea por linea pero no encuentro el dicho problema, igual investigue sobre los posibles errores pero no encontré nada al respecto, cabe aclarar que estoy probando y me vendrían bien sus consejos! Agradecería muchísimo su ayuda

Igual si existe una mejor forma de hacerlo, estaré encantado de leerla y ponerla en practica, me encanta aprender todo tipo de cosas, sin embargo esto es mas complejo para mi

**Index**:El index presenta una tabla con los usuarios registrados, a un lado aparece una pequeña tabla para registrar usuarios(update)

````
    <!--INICIO del cont principal-->
    
    <?php include("bd/db.php"); ?>
    
    <main class="container p-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <!-- MESSAGES -->
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) { ?>
          <div class="alert alert-<?= $_SESSION['message_type']?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <?= $_SESSION['message']?>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <?php session_unset(); } ?>
        
    <section>
          <!-- ADD TASK FORM -->
          <div class="card card-body">
            <form action="bd/save_task.php" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="Nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" autofocus>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="Apellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido" autofocus>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="Estado" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" autofocus>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" name="Telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono" autofocus>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="Detalles" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Detalles"></textarea>
    
              </div>
              <input type="submit" name="save_task" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Guardar alumno">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Detalles</th>
                <th style="width:50px;height:12px;">Registro</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>Editar/Borrar</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    
              <?php
              $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
              $result_tasks = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_tasks)) { ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Nombre']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Apellido']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Estado']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Detalles']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Creado']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Telefono']; ?></td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="bd/edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-secondary">
                      <i class="fas fa-marker"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="bd/delete_task.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-danger">
                      <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    </section>```

    /*
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Save_Task: Registrar nuevos datos, aquí me da error "Query Failed."
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    ``` <?php
    
    include('db.php');
    
    if (isset($_POST['save_task'])) {
      $title = $_POST['Nombre'];
      $apellido=$_POST['Apellido'];
      $lugar=$_POST['Estado'];
      $description = $_POST['Detalles'];
      $cellphone=$_POST['Telefono'];
      $query = "INSERT INTO users(Nombre, Apellido, Detalles, Telefono) VALUES ('$title', '$apellido','$lugar', '$description', '$cellphone')";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      if(!$result) {
        die("Query Failed.");
      }
    
      $_SESSION['message'] = 'Alumno Guardado';
      $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'success';
      header('Location: ../index.php');
    
    }
    
    ?>
    ```
    /*
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Edit.php :En este apartado se editan los datos ya colocados al igual tengo un error adicional,    "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\sys\vistas\sup.php:1) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sys\bd\edit.php on line 39" al revisar el archivo sup.php no encuentro el error, no tengo nada declarado en PHP
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    ``` <?php require_once "../vistas/sup.php" ?>
    <?php
    
    include("db.php");
    $title = '';
    $description= '';
    $Apellido = '';
    $Lugar = '';
    $description = '';
    $cellphone = '';
    
    if  (isset($_GET['id'])) {
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $title = $row['Nombre'];
        $apellido = $row['Apellido'];
        $lugar = $row['Estado'];
        $description = $row['Detalles'];
        $cellphone = $row['Telefono'];
      }
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      $title= $_POST['Nombre'];
      $apellido = $row['Apellido'];
      $lugar = $row['Estado'];
      $description = $_POST['Detalles'];
      $cellphone=$_POST['Telefono'];
    
    
      $query = "UPDATE users set Nombre = '$title',Apellido='$apellido',Estado='$lugar', Detalles = '$description', Telefono='$cellphone' WHERE id=$id";
      mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
      $_SESSION['message'] = 'Alumno editado con exito';
      $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'warning';
      header('Location: /index.php');
    }
    
    ?>
    
    
    
    </style>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <div class="container12">
      <h2>Editar alumno</h2>
      <form action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input name="Nombre" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" placeholder="Actualizar nombre">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input name="Apellido" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $Apellido; ?>" placeholder="Actualizar Apellido">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input name="Lugar" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $Lugar; ?>" placeholder="Actualizar estado">
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
              <input name="Telefono" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $cellphone; ?>" placeholder="Actualizar Telefono">
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
            <input name="Detalles" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" placeholder="Detalles">
            </div>
            <button class="btn-success" name="update">Actualizar</button>
              
    </button>
    
      </form>
    </div>
    ```

     /*
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Conexion.php
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    ``` <?php
    $servidor='localhost';
    $bd='caem';
    $user='root';
    $pass='';
    
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servidor.';dbname='.$bd,$user,$pass);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo"Ups error colega";
        exit;
    }
    
    
    if($_POST){
        session_start();
        $u = $_POST['t1'];
        $p = $_POST['t2'];
        $conexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $query = $conexion ->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username= :u AND clave= :p LIMIT 1;");
        $query->bindParam(":u", $u);
        $query->bindParam(":p", $p);
        $query->execute();
        $usuario = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
        if($usuario){
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario["username"];
            header("location:/sys/index.php");
            }else{
                echo "datos erroneos, verifica de nuevo";
            }
        }
    ?>```
````

Comment: ¿Por qué si tu conexión es PDO luego usas métodos de mysqli?

Comment: Estás declarando la conexión mediante PDO y luego estás utilizando  msqyli, ambos son formas de conectar a la base de datos, pero cada una es distinta de la otra y cada una tiene sus procedimientos así que lo que estas intentando no puede funcionar. Revisa como hacer conultas usando PDO.
Por otro lado ( tal vez se te haya olvidado indicar el nombre del archivo ), por lo que se ve en tu código, el select de los usuarios, lo tienes en db.php, ese código deberia estar en un php aparte, para que no te cause ningún error, ya que si se utiliza db.php en otro archivo, habrá código que falle.

Comment: ¿Por que intentas insertar 5 datos si solo llamas a 4?.
Mira como lo tienes: `$query = "INSERT INTO users (Nombre, Apellido, Detalles, Telefono) VALUES ('$title', '$apellido','$lugar', '$description', '$cellphone')";`
No veo ninguno que se refleje a la description.
Deveria ser así: `$query = "INSERT INTO users (Nombre, Apellido, Detalles, Description, Telefono) VALUES ('$title', '$apellido','$lugar', '$description', '$cellphone')";`